# When do videos appear in google's web search results?

Tags: seo, google, video

Sometimes videos appear in google's web search results (and not only in Google Videos).

- For a video to appear in the web search results, does it have to appear in Google Videos first?
- Does each and every video that appears in Google Videos has a chance to appear in google's web search results (given that the video is very relevant to the query, more relevant than all the other videos)?

Please note: I'm not asking about video sitemaps or mRSS. I'm just asking when do videos appear in google's web search results compared to when do videos appear in Google Videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [microformats](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=162163) to tell them it's a video ans what it's about.

UPDATE:

The results you see at the top of Google search results are from google video. They do the same thing for images. These results are separate from google search results. Basically you have to be a top search result in google video to be shown there.

I would assume that achieving high rankings in Google Video Search would be similar to regular Google Search. The context of the page (page title, headings, content) the video is on as well as link popularity etc, help them determine which videos are most relevant for a video search.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer my question. My question isn't "What to do? I can't find my video on google". The question is "Is the set of videos which appear in google's **web** search a subset of those which appear on Google Videos?". And: "My video is found in Google Videos but not in google's **web** search. Why? I mean, what parameters affect the presence of a video in google's **web** search?"

Comment: Is there anything else on the page besides the video? without it they won't have much to go on and that makes ranking page difficult (i.e. it ranks poorly). The microformats will help with that.

Comment: @John: I'm not talking about my video. I'm talking about a random video. Two questions about that random video: 1. Is being on Google Videos a necessary condition for being on Google's Web search? 2. Is being on Google Videos a sufficient condition for being on Google's web search?

Comment: 1) No 2) No; Video search has no direct correlation to web search

Comment: @John: Wait, maybe I'm still not clear. Sometimes, when you use google's web search engine you also get 2-3 video results. For example, when I search for "jon stewart" I get 3 video results in addition to the web pages results. Again: I get video results in the web page search engine. It looks like these videos are from Google Videos (because when I search for "jon stewart" in Google Videos I get these 3 results). Sometimes you get video results in the web search engine and sometimes you don't. My question is what is special about these 3 videos that make them appear in the regular web search?

Comment: Those results are from google video. They do the same thing for images. These results are separate from google search results. Basically you have to be a top search result in google video to be shown there.

Comment: @John: Thanks. Put what you said in your answer and I'll accept it. If you know more specific details on what makes a video appear in google's web search I'll be happy if you mention them.

Comment: Answer updated.